# Tiny query used to be sub-second speed, now takes 60+ seconds

Tags: sql-server-2012

Ok, I've got a monitoring process that runs the following query to make sure the databases are backing up regularly.  This process used to take 1-2 seconds for connection, query execution, and everything.  Now the process is timeing out and if I run the query in SMSS it takes over a minute.

```
SELECT D.name AS [database_name], D.recovery_model, BS1.last_backup, BS1.last_duration
FROM sys.databases D
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT BS.[database_name],
    DATEDIFF(HH,MAX(BS.backup_finish_date), GETDATE()) AS last_backup,
    DATEDIFF(MI,MAX(BS.backup_start_date),MAX(BS.backup_finish_date)) AS last_duration
    FROM msdb.dbo.backupset BS
    WHERE BS.type = 'L'
    GROUP BY BS.[database_name]
) BS1 ON D.name = BS1.[database_name]
ORDER BY D.[name]
```

Now the sub-select by itself still takes less than a second and returns about 20 rows (the *msdb.dbo.backupset* table has ~500K rows).  The *sys.databases* table has about only about 30 rows.  So I'm lost as to why this query now takes a minute to run.

The problem started after the C: drive was full for a few minutes so I thought maybe an index for corrupted. So I've rebuilt all the indexes (including PK) on the *msdb.dbo.backupset* table.  I can't find the *sys.databases* table so I'm guessing it's a "virtual table" or something?  I looked at the estimated execution plan but that stuff is mostly over my head.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Purge your backup history.

Comment: Can you upload the XML for the actual (not estimated) plan BTW.

Comment: Purging my backup history worked (at least took it down to 10 seconds which is good enough for my use case).  If you make that an answer instead of a comment then I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: 10 seconds for a "tiny query" still sounds poor. Can you upload the XML for the plan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The longer, more answer-y version of my comment**

Having 500k rows of backup information logged in msdb isn't really necessary for 30-ish databases. Even if you were taking log backups every minute, it would take a long time to get there.

What's a reasonable amount of backup information to retain? Probably as much as you retain physically. If you keep backups for a week, having backup history going back further than a week won't do you much good. I usually line the two up. If you're keen on keeping historical information, aggregate it in another table for reporting. The tables in [msdb can be a bottleneck](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/05/brents-backup-bottleneck-msdb/).

If you want more information on how to purge automagickally, [check out this write-up](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/msdb-history-not-purged/).

Answer (score 4):

> the sub-select by itself still takes less than a second and returns
>   about 20 rows ... Any suggestions?

In that case you may as well materialize it into a `#temp` table and join onto that instead.

```
SELECT BS.[database_name],
       DATEDIFF(HH, MAX(BS.backup_finish_date), GETDATE())                 AS last_backup,
       DATEDIFF(MI, MAX(BS.backup_start_date), MAX(BS.backup_finish_date)) AS last_duration
INTO   #BS1
FROM   msdb.dbo.backupset BS
WHERE  BS.type = 'L'
GROUP  BY BS.[database_name];

SELECT D.name AS [database_name],
       D.recovery_model,
       BS1.last_backup,
       BS1.last_duration
FROM   sys.databases D
       LEFT JOIN #BS1 BS1
         ON D.name = BS1.[database_name]
ORDER  BY D.[name];

DROP TABLE #BS1 ;
```

Comment: This worked and took the execute-time back down to sub-second times.  However, after researching the purging of backup history, that seems like the more "best practice" way of solving the issue.